# How to add theme support?

Tags: theme-development, themes, hooks, child-theme, add-theme-support

I figured this would have been a question already, but I haven't come across it.

**I'm wondering what the correct hook for checking [theme support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_theme_supports) is in a theme and also a plugin.**

```
function my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature()
    if (current_theme_supports( $feature )) {
        add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );            
        add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
    }
}
add_action( $hook, 'my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature');
```

So in the above example when/where should the `my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature` check, run in themes and plugins and is it necessary? Is it the same for both?

***Examples:***

`add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature');`

`add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature');`

`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_or_plugin_add_theme_support_feature');`

**Update:**

Actually I just found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135572/add-theme-supportmy-custom-feature/135573#135573), which is very similar.

Also, here's a similar [question I asked here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/206683/43806) which I was able to figure out using `add_theme_support` in a plugin... however, it doesn't work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really just depends on what you need to do here. The general method is to hook all your theme support features to `after_setup_theme` for some obvious reasons.

`after_setup_theme` is the first action hook available to themes to add any type of support the theme. Certain features has to be registered here and cannot be registered later. One feature that jumps to mind is support for post formats. `post_format` is a build-in taxonomy which is registered on `init`. If we skip the following actions:

- `auth_cookie_malformed`
- `auth_cookie_valid`
- `set_current_user`

`init` will be the next hook after `after_setup_theme` to do plugin and theme related stuff on. As `post_format` are registered on `init`, adding theme support here will be too late with the wrong priority. So if you need to check for theme support for post formats, you need to do that on `after_setup_theme` with a very low priority. I tend to use the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant value as priority or `PHP_INT_MAX + 1` . You can also maybe try `set_current_user` which runs after `after_setup_theme` and just before `init`

Generally, all build-in theme support features are executed on `after_theme_support` to keep consistancy in your code, but you should not rely on that at all. As [@toscho described in his answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135573/31545), `wp_loaded` is an excellent hook to use to check if a certain feature is already supported or not (*there are exceptions, see below note*). By the time `wp_loaded` fires, all theme support features should have been added, if not, then that theme is doing something very wrong and you really cannot compromise your code to adjust for a bad theme. All hooks after `wp_loaded` are concerned with content output and manipulating the ouput which will be send to browser.

### IMPORTANT NOTE

As I already stated, some features like post format support cannot be added on `init` or any hook after that as it is too late, so `wp_loaded` in this case would be way too late to add theme support for post formats. As I already stated you would need to hook your function as late as possible to `after_setup_theme`

### CONCLUSION

There is now real correct hook to use here. The hook would depend on the support feature. In general it would be safe to use `wp_loaded` to check for a specific ***custom*** support feature and in my opinion this would be the latest hook which you should use to add any type of theme support feature. For the build-in support features, `after_setup_theme` with a very low priority (*or even `set_current_user`*) should suffice as `init` is too late to add features like post formats